# angularjs $http is not recognized

Tags: jquery, angularjs, scriptaculous

I have jquery 1.10, scriptaculous. I fixed the conflict with `$` in my `jsp`. Now, I'm planning to implement angular in my code. I think i have conflict with $ between angular and scriptaculous. How do i resolve it ?

i'm using this in my code

```
$http({
                method: 'JSONP',
                url: '' }).then({});
```

I get the error  `Uncaught ReferenceError: $http is not defined`
How to fix it ?

Comment: Have you injected `$http` dependency in your controller?

Comment: you need to provide more details, like what your controller/service definition code looks like, where you inject ``$http``

Comment: a plunker or jsfiddle could be of great help

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject $http dependency into your controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    // Simple GET request example:
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/someUrl'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
      });
    });
```